# MP3 Mix Tape from a M3U files (Long audio file)

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3, recording

I wish to create a "Mix Tape" a long continues audio file (mp3, wave) from a M3U
file that contains 24 Hours of music / eg about mp3 500+ psongs .

Problem
every application i look at just creates the m3u file and does not have  the option for  saving  the files as one file .
I guess this  may be for copy write reason or for encoding mp3 licence

I have looked at...
Logic audio (dont have a Mac for this)
Cubases (note sure )
Wavelabs (note sure ) it will bring in a m3u

Audacity (Yes but just lines them up the audio files but  no overlap a)
Mix Pad (Yes but no beat match)
Virtual DJ (Yes everything but no save as , have to to play it with in real time 24Hrs real time)
Adobe audition ?
ffmpeg (just appends)
ffplay (saw some where can read the m3u

Last resort  just give the person the mp3 and the flies LOL

Comment: The requirement for beat-matching is hidden in the second to last paragraph so I would recommend making that clearer in your question. One possible option would be Mixmeister (https://www.mixmeister.com/express.php), however it's commercial software.

Comment: Creating a "mix tape" with the requirements that you seem to add as you go along in this question (gapless, some unknown overlap, beat matching) is far more complicated than you are giving it credit for. Sure they're not supremely difficult, but they are by no means trivial either. Chances are you need to find some specific DJ software (likely paid) and invest some time learning how to do what you want.

Comment: @Richard, Thank your for contribution,
Having gone back  to  an old computer system I knew i had this programs

However just viewed this application which has past it shelf life..
A online video post in 2020 detailed every floor that possible 
* Bad beat rescission 
* Importation of the music file ordering 
* Clipping of flies 

sound like a nigh mare
FYI One is an audio engineer 15 Years 
Programs in 6 different languages 
and has 8 Computers